# How to apply Rolle's theorem here

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a continous and differentiable function.

If  $f(0) =1$ and $f (1)^{3} + 2f (1) =5$, then prove there exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that: 
$$f'(c)=\frac{2}{2+3[f (c)]^2}$$

Comment: You could apply the Mean Value Theorem to $g(x)=(f(x))^3+2f(x)$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: ... after all, $f(x)^3+2f(x)$ is the *only* function you know anything about at $x=1$.

Comment: If you must use Rolle's Theorem, apply it to $h(x)=g(x)-(3+2x)$, where $g$ is as in my first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, $g(x)=f(x)^3+2f(x)-2x-3$ satisfies $g(0)=g(1)=0$, so by Rolle's theorem, there's $c\in(0,1)$ such that
$$0=g'(c)=3f(x)^2f'(x)+2f'(x)-2\implies f'(x)=\frac 2{3f(x)^2+2}$$
(we can divide since $3f(x)^2+2>0$)

Comment: Could plz tell how could u so easily find out what g(x) is?

Comment: @JessicaGtb You can evaluate $f(0)^3+2f(0)=3$ and $f(1)^3+2f(1)=5$, to use Rolle's theorem you need both evaluations to be $0$. And $2x+3$ is a linear function which is $3$ at $x=0$ and $5$ at $x=1$, it's the simplest thing you can subtract to get the desired form.